What is the current best algorithm to find if a simply connected region is uniquely tileable with dominoes?
I was reading both Thurston's and Fournier's papers on algorithms which detect whether or not a simply connected region is tileable using dominoes (1 by 2 rectangles) when I came across the section in Fournier's paper which talks about detecting whether or not a simply connected region is uniquely tileable with dominoes. The reason this piqued my interest is because I know that there have been improvements in Thurston's and Fournier's algorithms which detect tileability detailed in this paper, from Thurston's $O(n \log n)$ and Fournier's $O(n)$ to the paper's $O(p \log p)$, where $n$ is the area of the simply connected region and $p$ is the perimeter of the same region. From what I could tell, it is fairly easy to detect whether or not a simply connected region is uniquely tileable in $O(n)$ time, via the proposition from Fournier:

A figure is uniquely tileable if and only if its white and black tessellations coincide.

Where the black tesselation is simply the result of switching the roles of white and black squares. (the white and black squares come from the classic "chessboard" coloring of any region) Due to the proposition, one could simply run Fournier's algorithm twice, one with each coloring, and then simply check whether or not the tessellations are the same in $O(n)$ time. However, my question is whether or not we may do a similar thing to the paper that took Fournier's algorithm and improved its time complexity to $O(p \log p)$. IE, Does there exist an algorithm which checks whether or not a simply connected region is uniquely tileable with dominoes in $O(p \log p)$ or perhaps even faster? What is the fastest algorithm known so far?
